# Cannot enable kernel dynamic debugging on linux

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, kernel

I have enabled the `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG` flag in kernel config file, built & installed the kernel. Then, when I reboot, I can see `/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control`.

However, when I tried to dynamically enable a module like so:

```
sudo echo 'module xhci_hcd +p' > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
```

I got:

```
bash: /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control: Permission denied
```

Notice that I'm using `sudo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirection (with the `>` shell operator) is not performed as root. That's why you get a *permission denied* error. I suggest you run the whole command in a sub shell like:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'module xhci_hcd +p' > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control"
```

Answer (score 4):

Just check if you have booted into the correct version of the kernel after enabling `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG` ? Next check if debugfs is mounted.

Try with `-n` option (do not output the trailing newline)

```
echo -n 'module xhci_hcd +p' | sudo tee /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
```

Also try if you are able to debug a specific file for the ko:

```
echo -n 'file filename.c +p' | sudo tee /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
```